# Javascript adding value to object key:value adds its value 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I had this same issue happen to me some time back but managed to somehow fixed it. Now I can't remember what I did, but if anyone knows how to deal with this I would also like to see what I'm doing wrong to get this result.

What I'm doing:

```
for (let i = 0; i < zoneJSObject.length; i++) { // iterating the whole object
    if(zoneJSObject[i].Active === true) { // finding the active zone
        console.log("selectedWidgetID: ", selectedWidgetID)
        zoneJSObject[i].ZoneWidgets = [...zoneJSObject[i].ZoneWidgets, ...selectedWidgetID] // should add the new value as a WHOLE inside the key param
    }
}
console.log("zoneJSObject after addition: ",zoneJSObject)
```

What I'm getting:

[image]

I would just like to get the `selectedWidgetID` as a whole value inside ZoneWidgets. Also if you know why my code is splitting the integer into a array of single values I would appreciate your insight. As I can't see what would cause this...

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Don't spread `selectedWidgetID`, so remove the `...` prefix from it

Comment: ofcourse, I used `...` to add arrays to the object in a previous command and forgot to remove it when adding single strings. Wow didn't notice it at all, thanks @NickParsons